# TypeError: hammerhead.extend is not a function

Tags: node.js, testcafe

Don't know why I'm experiencing the following inside the package testcafe-hammerhead.

```
stiva@stiva-ThinkPad-T490:~/AC_Automation$ testcafe --version
Using locally installed version of TestCafe.
/home/stiva/AC_Automation/node_modules/testcafe-hammerhead/lib/utils/logger.js:44
const proxyLogger = hammerhead.extend('proxy');
                               ^

TypeError: hammerhead.extend is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/stiva/AC_Automation/node_modules/testcafe-hammerhead/lib/utils/logger.js:44:32)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1120:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:971:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:812:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/stiva/AC_Automation/node_modules/testcafe-hammerhead/lib/request-pipeline/context.js:24:34)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1120:10)
```

I have updated testcafe-hammerhead to its latest, 24.2.1 but it still happens whenever i try to use testcafe for anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this issue with the basic local TestCafe installation. Try deleting your dependencies and your "lock" file and install all dependencies again. Please note that you don't need to update the `testcafe-hamemrhead` dependency manually in your project, just install the latest TestCafe version. If the issue still appears, please open a new bug report with a complete example using [this template](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug-report.md).

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention that I deleted testcafe modules and did npm install to re install them but that did not help. But now I've tried removing the packages-lock file and that made it work. Thanks!